# Python3 not running programs

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I've had this problem for sometime now, but my issue is that I run the command my program is not run. You can see it does not print, and in this case I'm using a web scraper it does not even open up Chrome. I reinstalled python to see if that would fix anything but to no avail.

[Picture of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yphuw.png)
[Picture of my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rm94c.jpg)

Comment: Please provide actual code and execution results, not links to other sites

Comment: whats your `seleniumPractice.py` looks like? please provide the code.

Answer (score -1):

Have you ever looked at PATH in your computer? Maybe you may changed the path of python. Also, did you try another IDE? with this way maybe you can learn which one has the problem "computer, ide or python".

Comment: I copy and pasted that path directly to my code. I have also tried other programs with simple print statements to terminal and get the same result